# How do I change the max attribute in HTML by checking a box?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, attributes, onchange

I want to change the max attribute for an input element in HTML by checking or unchecking a checkbox by using the onchange attribute in HTML and JavaScript. However, the code that I have written does not change the max attribute and the default value remains the same when I check the relevant box.

I want to call the JavaScript function `max_events()` when I check or uncheck the box (first code snippet) and I want it to change the max attribute in the second code snippet.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="generatorOUT" id="generatorOUT" onchange="max_events(this);"> generator<br>
```

```
<input type="number" name="nevents" id='box2' oninput="calculate();" min="1" max="10000" required></td>
```

Here is my max_events function:

```
function max_events(checkboxElem) {
   if(document.getElementByID('generatorOUT').checked)
     document.getElementByID('box2').max = "1000";
   else document.getElementByID('box2').max = "10000";
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but `getElementByID` must be `getElementById`.

Comment: @CarlBinalla Yep, that was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be [**`getElementById`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) not `getElementByID`. Also you can use the passed object to the function to refer the current element.

```js
function max_events(checkboxElem) {
  var box = document.getElementById('box2');
  if(checkboxElem.checked)
   box.max = "1000";
  else box.max = "10000";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="generatorOUT" id="generatorOUT" onchange="max_events(this);"> generator<br>
<input type="number" name="nevents" id='box2' oninput="calculate();" min="1" max="10000" required/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I knew it was something silly like that. Thanks for the syntax advice, too! I'm pretty knew to this, as you can probably tell.